# How to create a script to create a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, ssms

I am using `SQL Server Management Studio 2017`. I'm having a table in my local machine. Let's say its name is `Email`. Inside the `Email` table, there is a column name `Language` and its value can be `'en'` or `'zh'`. Beside this `Language` column, there are some more columns.

Now my colleague also has the same table but different machine and he only has the rows where `Language` is `en`. He doesn't have the rows where Language is `zh` yet.

How can I use this software to generate a SQL script to insert data to his table but with rows only `where Language = 'zh'` so that both table will be the same.

To be more clear , I need to send him the INSERT script with also contains the values of the data, so that he can use to INSERT to his database in his local machine.

Or is it any way else?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into colleague.dbo.email ( . . . )
    select . . . 
    from my.dbo.email
    where language = 'zh';
```

Comment: But we are different machine , so what I want is a script file to send to his machine, in this file , the script will also contains the values

Comment: @NgocTuanLam . . . Just use a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways - the first is quick and requires no code, but you need to manually get rid of the rows you don't want yourself, the other is more flexible but you have to code it. There are also third party tools you can get to do this for you.

If you just want to do this once, you can do the following (this is from a different version of SSMS, but it should be similar)

right click on the database, select tasks, select generate scripts. Then pick the table you want, go next, then in the advanced settings find the "types of data to script" and change it to data. This should generate a script to load all the data from your table - you would need to edit it to just load the rows you want.

Another option is to write a script that basically makes the data you want yourself. You would need set it up to start with, and adjust it if you ever change the table format, but you can edit the selection script so that it only gets the data you want. I'm sure you could write a script that would create this automatically for you, but I've never needed one, so I haven't thought about it.

Something like this one

```
With baseRows as 
(
    --This bit gets the data you want
    Select E.*
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY ID) as RowNo
    From dbo.Email E
    Where E.Language = 'zh'  -- whatever selection you need here
)
, selectRows as
(
    --This bit creates the data select statments to set the data to import
    Select
            case when BR.RowNo = 1 then '' else 'Union All ' end
            + 'Select ' 
            + convert(varchar(10), BR.userID) + ' as userID, '  -- required integer example
            + case when BR.backupID is null then 'NULL' else CONVERT(varchar(10), BR.backupID) end + ' as backupID, '  -- nullable integer example
            + '''' + BR.Name + ''' as name, '  -- required nvarchar example
            + case when BR.groupname IS null then 'NULL' else '''' + BR.groupname + '''' end + ' as groupname, '  --nullable varchar example
            + CONVERT(varchar(2), BR.isActive) + ' as isActive, '  --bit example        
        as SQL
    from baseRows BR
)

Select  
    --This creates the insert command row (top row) of the final query
  'Insert into Email (
      userID
      , backupID
      , name
      , groupName
      , IsActive
)' as SQL
UNION ALL
Select SQL from baseRows   --and adds the data to the following rows
```

If you run this script, the output would be the script you are looking for to load the data into another machine.

Answer (score 0):

RightClick on Database name(table in which Database)--->Tasks--->Generate Scripts--->Next--->select specific database objects--->select Table--->Save to file = ADVANCED--->click on Advanced--->types of data to script = "Data Only"--->Give the path(where to store theinsert commands)